# Circle data in Angular view

Tags: angular, geometry

I have about 20 names in a json file,

with a slice pipe I have limited to show only 5 names..my question is how to make that names show dynamically in group 5 by 5. So...first show 5 names

`Jamie, James, Angel, Aria, Don`

and after 3 seconds hide that names and show next 5 names

`John, Doe, John, Richard, Doe`

etc...

This is a part of code where I tried to write it

```
        <a class="cities" href="#" *ngFor="let item of name | slice:0:5">
            <div *ngIf="item.size==='big'; else elseBlock">
                <div @bounceIn class="big-name">{{item.name}}</div>
            </div>
            <ng-template #elseBlock>
                <h3 @bounceIn class="small-name">{{item.name}}</h3>
            </ng-template>             
        </a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Pass variable into your 'slice:0:5' expression, change that variable depending on seconds using rxjs - Timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have a list of 20 names:

```
private names = [
    'Name 1',
    'Name 2',
    'Name 3',
    ...
    'Name 19',
    'Name 20'
]
```

And want to show 5 names every 5 seconds:

```
private showNumber = 5;
private showDelay = 5000; // 5000ms === 5s
```

You can subscribe to a timer that emits its iteration value (each 5 seconds value is increased by 1):

If we want to loop we need a subject:

```
private reset$ = new Subject();
```

And subscribe for example in the ngOnInit:

```
this.reset$.pipe(
  startWith(undefined),
  switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000))
).subscribe((val) => {
  const start = val * this.showNumber;
  this.shownNames = [...this.names].splice(start, this.showNumber);
  // If you want to loop and start at the beginning again
  if (start >= this.names.length) {
    this.reset$.next();
  }
});
```

Explanation:

The timer gets called every 5 seconds `timer(0, 5000)`.

We copy our names with `[...this.names]` and splice it so we get an array with the needed elements.

We have a public variable `public shownNames = []` which we assign our results to.

In the View/Template we can now always iterate over `shownNames`

An example is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-agvwkc

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can solve this use rxjs - Timer,

```
const sliceExpression = -5;

const source = Rx.Observable.timer(1000, 1000);
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5......
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => {
   
  if(val%5==0)
    {
      sliceExpression += 5;
      console.log("Change your 'slice:0:5' expression here.");
      console.log(sliceExpression, sliceExpression+5);
    }

});
```

Working example into following link,
[JSBin Example](https://jsbin.com/siyerafuli/edit?js,console)